# canvas.drawPaint results in different view on emulator and pixel phone

Tags: android, android-canvas, virtual-reality, daydream

I just got my daydream headset so I tried running my vr app on it.

I was expecting the view to be like what I have seen on the emulator:
[image: vr view on emulator]

where there is a semi-transparent panel showing three days of weather information.
but what is shown on the pixel phone is a completely opaque background.

My code for drawing the panel is like this

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setColor(Color.rgb(160, 160, 160));
paint.setAlpha(50);
canvas.drawPaint(paint);
```

The emulator and the physical device have exactly the same api version
[api versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVGFP.png)

So I am wondering how I can get the pixel phone to display the same view that is displayed on the emulator. Thank you.